# Android Sdk Development with ui and api calls

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sdk, build.gradle

I have an app running live on the play store. Now I want to add another module or say it an SDK as the implementation dependency in the Gradle file. I have tried creating a new module in the project but the res folder is not available in it. it is important for me as I have activities and api calls in my sdk .

Basically, what I need is if I have a button, and clicking on that should open an activity from the new module or SDK I have to develop.

At last I have to give the implementation link for the library which needs to be in Gradle file of the projects main app .

Also, i need to do this in kotlin

How to approach this? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be sure that the reference of the new module was declared in settings.gradle with `include ':package-name'`

If you want to make the code of the new module available for another you need to declare it in the gradle file of the module where you want to use.

```
dependencies {
   implementation project(':package-name')
}
```

Comment: How can i use activities and api call in that new module i am creating

Comment: To use activities or other resources of Android frame work you had to set your module as a Android Module. In the build gradle of this module add "apply plugin: 'com.android.library'". 

About Api calls, I don't know how to answer you precisely. I think using Ktor or Retrofit istances with Rxjava or coroutines.